# How can I catch a nil error when trying to select a row in a UIPickerView?

Tags: swift, uipickerview, swift4, uivewcontroller

Apparently, if you try to get an element out of a `UIPickerView` in `viewWillAppear` the first time a view is run, the app will crash with a returned `nil` error.

If I comment out the the following line and run the app, all works fine. Then I uncomment out the following line and run again, it works fine and continues to work fine.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    myPicker.selectRow(0, inComponent: 0, animated: true)
}
```

I have no idea what the difference is. Maybe there is something else going on in the app. Is there a way to catch that initial `nil` and just swallow it? It would mimic the first access of the view and having the code commented out. After the first access of the view, `nil` won't be returned.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/WorkWithViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH6-SW3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the picker is declared as implicit unwrapped optional by default just optional chain it:

```
myPicker?.selectRow(0, inComponent: 0, animated: true)
```

Comment: Nope. Still get: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value.

Comment: Really? This is quite improbable with this code and the assumption.

Comment: I've found the issue. The thing that is supposed to be returning 0 is returning nil.

Comment: It's a bit confusing. In the code nothing is returned nowhere.

Answer (score 1):

You should check whether the picker is nil and whether it has at least one component/row in that component.

```
if let myPicker = myPicker,
    myPicker.numberOfComponents > 0,
    myPicker.numberOfRows(inComponent: 0) > 0 {
    myPicker.selectRow(0, inComponent: 0, animated: true)
}
```

Alternatively, you can "swallow" the first call of `viewWillAppear` with a boolean:

```
var firstViewWillAppearTime = true

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    if firstViewWillAppearTime {
        firstViewWillAppearTime = false
    } else {
        myPicker.selectRow(0, inComponent: 0, animated: true)
    }
}
```